# How to create a custom menu has normal website?

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-menu

I am creating a magento store and according to the design I need to create a custom menu with custom css,js. So can anyone help me to figure out this. I am new to magento CMS.

Comment: Not sure if this question is magento related or not as you haven't said if the menu needs to be content managed. If it doesn't then it's a simple HTML, css question